# How to use OpenCV's cv::Mat& to to obtain H.264's “Motion Vector”?

Tags: ios, opencv, h.264, avcapturesession

I am using OpenCV iOS SDK.

While capturing with the device preset `AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720`, I would like to get **motion vectors** from h.264 frame, at 30 fps speed.

I want to get numerical vectors and I believe OpenCV can be helpful. But it's not easy for me to research about it quickly.

What OpenCV `cv::Mat` **methods** should I use?

Is it more like finding correct **iterator** to extract motion vectors?

Does it involve **encoding captured video data into h.264 frame before** doing anything?

Comment: added link to project that probably can help you.

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV doesn't implement the h.264 encoder but uses external libraries to compress videos, you can see how it is done on ios [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_ios_video_camera.mm#L354). If you want to extract the motion vectors, you need to find a h.264 decoder that returns them or modify an open source one to do so.

[This project](https://github.com/vadimkantorov/mpegflow) probably can help you.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can calculate motion vectors directly: you should take a look at the [Optical FLow algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html).

To get going with iOS and openCV, you might want to check out my starter project ([Swift](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch) or [Objective-C](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVStitch)). As the C++ openCV code is cleanly separated from Swift and Objective-C, you can dump the photo-stitching part in the example quite easily and replace it with some optical-flow processing -  this [sample code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp) from the openCV distribution  may help.

I have no idea if you will achieve your required framerate doing it this way, and it certainly won't give you the same result as H.264-encoded motion vectors. Extracting them directly from H.264-encoded files is a really tempting way to go (as I see you are trying). Like you, I am trying to solve this using AVFoundation. If I get there, I will post a reply to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407273/how-to-extract-motion-vectors-from-h-264-avc-cmblockbufferref-after-vtcompressio).