# How to extract motion vectors from H.264 AVC CMBlockBufferRef after VTCompressionSessionEncodeFrame

Tags: ios, avfoundation, h.264, motion-detection, video-toolbox

I'm trying read or understand **`CMBlockBufferRef`** representation of **`H.264 AVC`** 1/30 frame.

The buffer and the encapsulating `CMSampleBufferRef` is created by using **`VTCompressionSessionRef`**.
https://gist.github.com/petershine/de5e3d8487f4cfca0a1d

H.264 data is represented as AVC memory buffer, `CMBlockBufferRef` from the compressed sample.

**Without fully decompressing again**, I'm trying to extract **`motion vectors or predictions`** from this `CMBlockBufferRef`.
I believe that for the fastest performance, **byte-by-byte reading** from the data buffer using **`CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer()`** should be necessary.

However, I'm having trouble finding *the right way* to read the data buffer, with the intention to find and extract `motion vectors or predictions`.

Is there no way at all, without decompressing, or using `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question completely. Are you trying to extract motion vectors from a h264 raw bit-stream? If that is the case, you can do it by parsing the bit-stream.

Comment: @ARK Because of limited knowledge, bit-stream parsing is exactly what I want to learn. Can you guide me to a kind of lessen which teach me how to do it?

Comment: Learning Bit-stream parsing is quite a task. Sure, I can help you to get better understanding. May be you can start with ffmpeg or libav code. What exactly is your objective? It may be simpler to tweak ffmpeg or libav code to get the needful, rather than spending time to learn it.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @ErikAigner Unfortunately, I couldn't make enough to re-visit this problem. It's really difficult problem.